# Passing large data sets between forms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a step by step form that transforms large sets of data in batches. I want to have the data saved to the database only on the last step. The way I've seen to create forms like this is to save the data in session storage.

```
session[:stored_data] = large_dataset
```

But this gives me a CookieOverflow error when trying to save to it.

What are my other options? Am I stuck with saving the data to the database between steps?

Comment: You can have Rails store your session in Redis or a database to get around this cookie overflow problem.

Comment: That would be ideal, but not sure that's really an option for me unfortunately. This is for a legacy codebase.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually store it in the form itself.

On the first form you might have...

```
<%= f.text_field :name_of_dog %>
```

...and on the second form you could store the first form's fields but in a hidden field.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :name_of_dog %>
```

This way you carry the data through all the subsequent forms and when the final form is submitted, you have the complete data you need to persist to the database.

I do this for single db records where the amount of information may be overwhelming for the end user or when you're displaying a limited amount of record data per page (say, because you're in an iframe).

I often also have an attr_accessor called something like `:page` so when the create or edit action is called I know which page has submitted.